# Two Dimensional AtomicInteger array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, atomic

Hey so I'm wondering how can I make [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) a two dimensional array, From what I've found on javadocs [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) is only single dimension.

```
int[] newArray = new int[100];
AtomicIntegerArray atomicarray = new AtomicIntegerArray(newArray);
```

Which creates a AtomicIntegerArray of size 100. But I would like an atomicarray with two dimensions. I've tried doing..

```
AtomicInteger[][] atomicArray = new AtomicInteger[100][100];
atomicArray[00][00].set(1);
```

But I am met with..

> java.lang.NullPointerException at nz.ac.massey.threadpool.MyClass.(MyClass.java:20)

So any ideas? thanks! :)... I haven't done much work with Atomic variables before.

if this isn't possible how can I minimic a regular primitive integer two dim array into a AtomicInteger two dim array?

Comment: You created an array of null's, you need to initialize every object: `atomicArray[0][0] = new AtomicInteger();`

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but if you can't diagnose a NullPointerException, it's probably much too early to mess with concurrency/multithreading issues. And without the code, it's impossible to make the diagnostic for you.

Comment: @alaster thanks! I have another question (extended from the last) is because I will iterating through all 100 objects. and I'm only initializing 20-30 objects, how can I get my uninitialized objects to not come up with a nullexception?

Comment: `NullPointerException` is thrown when you call array[someIndex] when this object is null. If you want to use it you must initialize it before. Or just don't call this object at all. You can use lazy initialize: `if (array[someIndex] == null) { array[someIndex] = new AtomicInteger(); }`
But i think @JBNizet is right. AtomicInteger used in complicated code

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but its for an assignment, so I don't really get a choice.

Comment: @JBNizet also... nullexception are pretty self explanatory, the nullexception is completely irrelevant to the question. but thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate *all* of the positions in the matrix before accessing them, something like this:

```
atomicArray[i][j] = new AtomicInteger();
```

Or this, if you want to initialize each atomic integer in a certain initial value:

```
atomicArray[i][j] = new AtomicInteger(initialValue);
```

That, for all `i,j` positions in the matrix. Normally you'd do this using a couple of nested `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        atomicArray[i][j] = new AtomicInteger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I now have the Game of life running in parallel :)

Answer (score 6):

Just create a one-dimensional array of length `m * n`, you then need a function that maps a pair of integers `(i, j)` to one integer. `i * n + j` is a good start. Assuming `m` is the number of rows and `n` the number of columns.

It is a good idea to keep all of your integers inside the AtomicIntegerArray. Or you'll have to deal with concurrency your self.